# Is it possible to access a friends Instagram pictures without his access_token?

Tags: instagram, access-token, instagram-api

I heard that Instagram recently changed their APIs and I have a related question to that.

Let's assume I would like to build an "Instagram feed app of people I follow". So this app would just show me the pictures of all people I follow. From what I understand this would be possible, but I would always have same manual effort:

From the [Instagram developer website](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) I understand that I need the `access_token` from all my friends.

1. Do I understand that correctly?

   This would mean every time I follow someone new, I would have to get his/her `access_token` manually and add it into my app.
2. Do I understand this correctly or is there a programmatic/automated way to get the needed `access_token` from the new followed person?

Comment: No one an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. This is not possible at the moment. I'm not sure how you would get the access token of friends. You would have to have them login as well. BTW: This seems to be the way facebook is going (since they now control Instagram). They require that both friends have authorized your app and then they will list their followers.